# Python optimize.minimize methods having **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, keyword-argument

How do we optimize a method that has **kwargs present?

My method looks like the following and yields a TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'positional argument but 2 were given.

```
def f(**z):
    z1 = z.pop('z1', 0)
    z2 = z.pop('z2', 1)
    z3 = z.pop('z3', 2)
    return z1**3 + 4*z2 - 9*z3


initialGuess = {'z1' : 1, 'z3' : 3 }
parameter = {'z2': 2}
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(f, initialGuess, args=(parameter,), method='TNC')
print(result.x)
```

Does it indicate that we can't optimize a method that takes **kwargs?

Comment: Initial guess has to be changed into a single positional argument, an array.  Write a cover function if needed `def g(x, z2): return f(z1=x[0], z2=z2, z3=x[1])` or something like that.

Comment: That means we can't optimize a method with **kwargs directly. Also I think in the cover method we need to pass on the f(**z) method, right?

`def g(f, x, z2): 
         return f(z1=x[0], z2=z2, z3=x[1])`